# Parse same key but with different values to a data class in kotlin

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, data-class

I am working on an API implementation with a third-party service, but the response I am getting from that API is not consistent, it has the same keys but different values of that key and I am not able to parse it, I tried it with Any, but can not get access to values as from the key, So If someone has achieved this or can suggest then it will be a great help, Thanks in advance.
This is my JSON object response for example

```
 "data": [
              {
                "values": [
                  0.0,
                  0.2
                ],
                "type": "A"
              },
              {
                "values": [
                  [
                    [
                      -0.2,
                      5.4
                    ],
                    [
                      -0.2,
                      5.5
                    ],
                    [
                      0.3,
                      56.4
                    ],
                    [
                      0.5,
                      6.4
                    ]
                  ]
                ],
                "type": "P",
                "other": {
                  "type": "n",
                  "properties": {
                    "name": "u"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
```

The above is how I am getting a response, But I am not able to find a proper way to parse it in a data class.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson framework.

```
val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
val treeNode = objectMapper.readTree("your_json_in_string")
```

`treeNode` is an `JsonNode` that contains your json tree.
See: [jackson framework](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Comment: This is part of the response, I am passing response to the main data class  @thorny

Comment: If the response is dynamic you cannot insert it in a given class because it always varies. That's why you need a tree construction